# Es posible asignar un dominio .com.ve a una aplicacion web con Heroku?

Tags: heroku, dns

Llevo tiempo tratando de asignar el dns de un dominio .com.ve (Dominios nacionales de Venezuela) pero no lo he conseguido.

Leyendo la documentacion de Heroku, al parecer Heroku solo es compatible con dns de tipo CNAME, lo cual es incompatible con los formatos que me ofrece el proveedor de dns de Venezuela [Link Aqui](https://registro.nic.ve/).

Sin embargo quisiera preguntar, alguien ha posido hacer eso? Utilizar un dominio venezolano para correr una aplicacion en Heroku.

Comment: El CNAME tiene más que ver con el nameserver que con el registrar. Hay algunos proveedores de hospedaje de DNS que ofrecen servicios gratuitos, busca en Google.